# Azure App Service to connect to on-premises REST API

Tags: c#, azure

I have an App Service web app running in .net which is trying to connect to a REST API which is available inside our on-premises. I created a VM machine in Azure and from there I am able to connect to the REST API using site to site VPN, but not through app service. I am not getting a clear picture if App Service would support VPN connectivity or I have to use hybrid connection approach.

I am sure this post is not clear. Any help to get started would help me get going.

Thanks,
Venkat

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve this :

**VNet Integration**

A Standard, Premium, or Isolate app service plan offers the ability for an app service to connect with a virtual network via a point-to-site VPN. The virtual network must have a VPN gateway that is Basic/Dynamic, VpnGw1 or a higher size, and configure for point-to-site connectivity.

[image]

Once an app service is connected to a virtual network, you can:

Enable the app service to talk with Azure virtual machines on that virtual network.
Hop to on-premises via site-to-site VPN connections also make by that gateway.
The point-to-site VPN connection inherits the SLA of the gateway in question. There are some limitations:

The connection speed is limited to what the gateway can offer (80-100Mpbs using the Basic size gateway).
An app service plan can support connections to just 5 virtual networks.
An app service can connect to just one virtual network.

**Hybrid Connection**

This is a feature that I really like and in conversations that I’ve had, it seems to be an approach that few are aware of. However, it has been available for years in the Basic, Standard, and Premium plans.

[image]

**Azure Service Environment (ASE)**

The ASE is a solution where you deploy one or more single-tenant Isolated tier app services plans in an environment that is connected to a virtual network. This means that every instance in the app service plan is already in the virtual network, and can communicate directly with Azure virtual machines in the same network without needing any VPN or hybrid connections.

An internal ASE, deployed using an internal load balancer presents your Isolated tier app services to users/systems via a single private IP address. You can route to that private IP address in a number of ways:

A web application gateway
Third-party firewall appliances (virtual machines) in a front-end subnet
From remote or on-premises networks using a site-to-site VPN or ExpressRoute connection

[image]